# How to create a dynamic variable to perform a count with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have these variables:

```
call = 0
brake = 0
```

Then I read several files where in each line there is 1 word. These words/string coincide with the name of the variables.

```
lines.each do |line|
  line += 1 #line == 'call' therefore you wish to do >> call += 1
end
```

Since I have too many variables in the program something like that would simplify the process a lot.

Furthermore, it could be reused in other scenarios of the same program.

Comment: The typical way to do this would be to define a Hash, and then to keep the counts there. `counts = Hash.new(0); counts["foo"] += 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a quick counter table:

```
counter = Hash.new(0)
```

Where you can then do:

```
lines.each do |line|
  counter[line.chomp] += 1
end
```

Now you have a count of lines.

The `chomp` is there to remove any newline characters that might contaminate matches.

Think in terms of data, not in terms of variables. The initial approach you had depends on referencing variables dynamically which sort of misses the point. You want all your counters to be grouped together so you can do things like *iterate over them* and *inspect their state as a whole*.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: You can add one thing. If line data has any space, line.chomp  will create the hash key with space.


lines.each do |line|
  counter[line.scan(/\w+/).first] += 1
end

Comment: @TheVinspro The whole input stream can be broken into words using `scan` if that's the desired outcome.